# median raster value for polygons by attribute that is not unique

Tags: r, raster, terra

Given this this raster and polygon dataset

```
 f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra") 
 r <- rast(f)
 fs <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
 v <- vect(fs)
```

How can I extract the median value of the raster cells for polygons with the same value of "NAME_1" in `v`, and add this to the attributes of `v`?

Please note that "NAME_1" is not unique in `v`:

```
v
# class       : SpatVector 
# geometry    : polygons 
# dimensions  : 12, 6  (geometries, attributes)
# extent      : 5.74414, 6.528252, 49.44781, 50.18162  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# source      : lux.shp
# coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
# names       :  ID_1   NAME_1  ID_2   NAME_2  AREA   POP
# type        : <num>    <chr> <num>    <chr> <num> <int>
# values      :     1 Diekirch     1 Clervaux   312 18081
#                   1 Diekirch     2 Diekirch   218 32543
#                   1 Diekirch     3  Redange   259 18664
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute the median for all *geometries*, you can do

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra") )
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))

v$median = extract(r, v, fun=median, na.rm=TRUE, ID=FALSE)
v
# class       : SpatVector 
# geometry    : polygons 
# dimensions  : 12, 7  (geometries, attributes)
# extent      : 5.74414, 6.528252, 49.44781, 50.18162  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# source      : lux.shp
# coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
# names       :  ID_1   NAME_1  ID_2   NAME_2  AREA   POP median
# type        : <num>    <chr> <num>    <chr> <num> <int>  <num>
# values      :     1 Diekirch     1 Clervaux   312 18081  467.1
#                   1 Diekirch     2 Diekirch   218 32543  333.9
#                   1 Diekirch     3  Redange   259 18664  377.4
```

Since "NAME_1" has the same value for multiple geometries, we have to do a bit more work. You can do either

```
a <- aggregate(v, "NAME_1")
e <- extract(r, a, fun=median, na.rm=TRUE)
e$NAME_1 <- a$NAME_1[e$ID]
e$ID <- NULL
ve <- merge(v, e, by="NAME_1")
```

or

```
ee <- extract(r, v, na.rm=TRUE)
ee$NAME_1 <- v$NAME_1[ee$ID]
ee <- aggregate(ee[,2,drop=FALSE], ee[,"NAME_1",drop=FALSE], median, na.rm=TRUE)
vee <- merge(v, ee, by="NAME_1")

values(vee)
#         NAME_1 ID_1 ID_2           NAME_2 AREA    POP elevation
#1      Diekirch    1    1         Clervaux  312  18081     422.0
#2      Diekirch    1    2         Diekirch  218  32543     422.0
#3      Diekirch    1    3          Redange  259  18664     422.0
#4      Diekirch    1    4          Vianden   76   5163     422.0
#5      Diekirch    1    5            Wiltz  263  16735     422.0
#6  Grevenmacher    2    6       Echternach  188  18899     288.5
#7  Grevenmacher    2    7           Remich  129  22366     288.5
#8  Grevenmacher    2   12     Grevenmacher  210  29828     288.5
#9    Luxembourg    3    8         Capellen  185  48187     314.0
#10   Luxembourg    3    9 Esch-sur-Alzette  251 176820     314.0
#11   Luxembourg    3   10       Luxembourg  237 182607     314.0
#12   Luxembourg    3   11           Mersch  233  32112     314.0
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry, I should have said compute the median for each category in the column NAME_2. In my real data, I have separated polygons with the same name. So how can I have the median of each category in "NAME_2", for instance, please?

Comment: I assume you mean "NAME_1"? Otherwise, the answer already covers it. Please edit your question to make clear what you want.

Comment: Yes you are right I meant NAME_1, thanks.